# Change alignment of UIDatePicker with .compact datePickerStyle - iOS 14 and later

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, ios14

in iOS 14, Apple introduced new `UIDatePicker` styles. I am using the `.compact` style for my `preferredDatePickerStyle` on a `UIDatePicker`.

```
timedatePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
timedatePicker.backgroundColor = .white
timedatePicker.clipsToBounds = true
timedatePicker.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
timedatePicker.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
timedatePicker.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
timedatePicker.date = selectedDate
timedatePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
timedatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
timedatePicker.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
timedatePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: Date())
timedatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setDate(sender:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
view.addSubview(timedatePicker)
```

I am setting constraints in code:

```
let constraints = [
    timedatePicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0),
    timedatePicker.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 32.0),
    timedatePicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timedateLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
    timedatePicker.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -32.0)
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

This all works, but the actual `compact` content view *inside* the `UIDatePicker` is left-justified in the `view` so it is jammed right up against the left side with lots of whitespace on the right, and therefore not centered.

[image: Screenshot]

I can't seem to find a way to make this centered. `contentMode` and `contentHorizontalAlignment` fail to effect any change.

Anyone have any experience solving this (as in changing the alignment)?

Comment: I'm not being a smarty-pants; I'm quite serious. We've all experienced it and we're pretty much exasperated, just as you probably are. Apple has introduced this bizarre interface element that doesn't fit with anything else and can't be controlled and formatted in the normal way. There isn't any known solution (unless they've improved things in the iOS 15 beta; I haven't looked).

Comment: How were you able to modify the text color on uidatepicker? I am unable to do so on iOS 14 with compact style

Comment: Glad its not just me, did anyone ever find a solution, I can't make the thing align to the left instead of the right

Answer (score 0):

My quickest solution to this was to place the DatePicker in a UIView and then constrain the picker to equal height, centerX and centerY of the UIView.
This wrapper view I then placed into a UIStackView together with my other 5 items which were already residing there.
I had to go this route since I found that on IOS 16 the DatePicker centered without a problem, on IOS 14 however I needed the wrapper.